# Read cookie in router or component inside a vue app

Tags: javascript, http, vue.js, cookies

I serve a url(*/webapp/callback) in a vue.js app that is redirected(http 302) from another application, which passes some cookies that I want to read when the component is mounted and store in vuex state. Is there a way I could do this?

Something like `cookie.get[testcookie]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library,
https://github.com/cmp-cc/vue-cookies

Then you can use it like,

```
// get cookie
$cookies.get(keyName);

// remove cookie
$cookies.remove(keyName [, path [, domain]])
```

Comment: I tried this, but get null. Although I can see the cookie present in application storage cookies in developer tool.